# How can I add a list of data to Sqflite in flutter

Tags: sql, flutter, sqlite

I am trying to add multiple data to Sqflite in flutter but it's not working.

For example I want to add a list of a Todo class.

Pls if there's any help I'll appreciate.

I tried writing a raw SQL to add the list of data but it didn't work. All I was getting was bunch of errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually there is no way you could insert all data by one function but you could do it with help of loops.
you could tiger loop while the length of the list and do the insert while its true! its too simple

```dart
List<Todo>todos=[Todo('example'),Todo('example'),Todo('example'),Todo('example')];
//here should be the db provide class
for(Todo iteam in todos){
   // do the insert functionality
   // here try the way you insert single todo in db
   db.insert(iteam.toJson())
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, you saved the day. It works out of the box am really grateful.

Answer (score 1):

To add a list of Todo class objects to Sqflite in Flutter, you can follow these steps:

1. Create a database helper class that extends the `DatabaseProvider` class from the `sqflite` package. You can use this class to define methods for creating, opening, and updating the database.

```dart
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';

class DatabaseHelper {
  static final DatabaseHelper instance = DatabaseHelper._instance();
  static Database? _db;

  DatabaseHelper._instance();

  Future<Database> get db async {
    if (_db == null) {
      _db = await _initDb();
    }
    return _db!;
  }

  Future<Database> _initDb() async {
    final String dbPath = await getDatabasesPath();
    final String path = join(dbPath, 'todo_db.db');

    final todoDb = await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _createDb);

    return todoDb;
  }

  void _createDb(Database db, int version) async {
    await db.execute(
        'CREATE TABLE todos(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, title TEXT, description TEXT, isDone INTEGER)');
  }

  Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> getTodosMapList() async {
    final Database db = await instance.db;
    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> result = await db.query('todos');
    return result;
  }

  Future<int> insertTodoList(List<Todo> todoList) async {
    final Database db = await instance.db;
    final Batch batch = db.batch();

    for (Todo todo in todoList) {
      batch.insert('todos', todo.toMap());
    }

    final List<dynamic> result = await batch.commit();
    final int affectedRows = result.reduce((sum, element) => sum + element);
    return affectedRows;
  }
}
```

2. Define a `Todo` class that contains the data you want to store in the database. In this example, the `Todo` class has four properties: `id`, `title`, `description`, and `isDone`.

```dart
class Todo {
  int? id;
  String? title;
  String? description;
  bool? isDone;

  Todo({
    this.id,
    this.title,
    this.description,
    this.isDone = false,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'title': title,
      'description': description,
      'isDone': isDone ? 1 : 0,
    };
  }

  static Todo fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Todo(
      id: map['id'],
      title: map['title'],
      description: map['description'],
      isDone: map['isDone'] == 1,
    );
  }
}
```

3. In the `insertTodoList` method of the `DatabaseHelper` class, create a batch object and use the `insert` method to insert each `Todo` object into the database. Finally, use the `commit` method to execute the batch.

```dart
Future<int> insertTodoList(List<Todo> todoList) async {
  final Database db = await instance.db;
  final Batch batch = db.batch();

  for (Todo todo in todoList) {
    batch.insert('todos', todo.toMap());
  }

  final List<dynamic> result = await batch.commit();
  final int affectedRows = result.reduce((sum, element) => sum + element);
  return affectedRows;
}
```

4. To use the `insertTodoList` method to insert a list of `Todo